# ¿Cuál es el máximo tamaño de un arreglo en el lenguaje de programación R?

Tags: r

Así como indica el título, necesito averiguar el máximo tamaño soportado para una variable arreglo en el lenguaje de programación R.

Esto debido a que me encuentro estudiando sus limitaciones como lenguaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El "arreglo" más básico en **R** es un vector, el tamaño máximo para estos tipos de objetos (en realidad para cualquier otro tipo) depende de varios factores, la [documentación oficial](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) explica en detalle esto. **R** no tiene límites específicos sino que usará la memoria que le permita el SO usar. Entre los factores que influyen en este número, tenemos:

- El sistema operativo (Window/Linux) y en algunos casos las versiones de éstos
- La arquitectura: 32/64 bits
- Eventuales limitaciones a nivel de cada proceso
- Limitaciones de recursos impuestas por los sistemas operativos

De forma orientativa, se podría decir:

#### En Unix

El límite de espacio de dirección de memoria es específico del sistema: los SOs de 32 bits imponen un límite de no más de **4Gb**, pero a menudo es de **3Gb**. Los ejecutables de 32 bits en un SO de 64 bits tiene límites similares. Los ejecutables de 64 bits tendrán un límite específico del sistema esencialmente infinito (por ejemplo, **128Tb** para Linux en arquitecturas x86_64).

#### En Windows

El límite de espacio de dirección es de **2Gb** en Windows de 32 bits, a menos que se haya cambiado el valor predeterminado del sistema operativo para permitir más (hasta **3Gb**). Véase https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx. En la mayoría de las versiones de 64 bits de Windows, el límite para una versión de 32 bits de R es de **4 Gb**, para las más antiguas es de **2 Gb**. El límite para una compilación de 64 bits de R (impuesto por el sistema operativo) es de **8Tb**.

Normalmente no es posible asignar más de **2Gb** a un único vector en una compilación de 32 bits de R, incluso en Windows de 64 bits debido a las preasignaciones del SO.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!